# Is error checking in VS Code exclusively tied to the file extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've associated `.es6` files with the JavaScript React language mode by adding this to my VS Code settings (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`):

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.es6": "javascriptreact"
}
```

And when I have an `.es6` file open in VS Code, the language mode is indeed "JavaScript React".

But error checking seems to be treating the file as though it were a plain `.js` file. For files containing React code, there are lots of red squiggles indicating errors like `[js] ':' expected.` or `[js] '>' expected.`.

On the other hand, if I rename the file with a `.jsx` extension, the red squiggles disappear.

Is there a way to convince VS Code to apply React-flavor error checking to e.g. `.es6` files?

P.S. I'm using VS Code v1.9.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on TypeScript and JavaScript support for VSCode.

This is a bug and I have submitted a [PR with the fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/20351). This should be in the next [insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders)

Comment: outstanding, glad to hear.  How quickly do you imagine this'll be in a regular release?

Comment: We try to ship on a monthly cadence, so VSCode 1.10 is on track for the end of February / early March

Comment: a possibly similar problem with JS configuration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214814/remove-decorators-error-in-visual-studio-code

btw - **loveing** VS Code so far - great job.