# Remove decorators error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm getting

> [js] Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

On a decorated JavaScript class.

My jsconfig.json file, at the root of my JavaScript files, looks like this.

```
{
    "experimentalDecorators": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I believe your `jsconfig.json` should instead be:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true
    }
}
```

Comment: For other, here is the link to the reference page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_jsconfig-options

And here is a snippet: Do not be confused by compilerOptions. This attribute exists because jsconfig.json is a descendent of tsconfig.json, which is used for compiling TypeScript.

Comment: version 1.77 2023 ... don't works

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true
  }
 }
```